# Google App Engine:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver registerMBeans: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, jdbc

Google App EngineにWebアプリケーションを配備しました。配備自体は成功したのですが、サイトにアクセスすると下記のようなエラーが出てしまいます。JDK7を使用、JDBCはojdbc7.jarとmysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jarを試しましたが、いずれも同じエラーが発生してしまいます。
DBはGoogle Cloud SQLにMySQLのデータベースを配備してあります。
どなたかお分かりになる方いらっしゃいましたら、アドバイスお願いします。よろしくお願いいたします。

> oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver registerMBeans: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean.
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.management.ManagementFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
>     at >com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.stub.java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.(ManagementFactory.java)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans(OracleDriver.java:327)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver$1.run(OracleDriver.java:209)
>     at >com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.security.AccessController_.doPrivileged(AccessController_.java:34)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.(OracleDriver.java:205)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at >sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at >sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:370)
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:373)
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:510)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:490)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.loadInitialDrivers(DriverManager.java:490)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.(DriverManager.java:100)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.(Driver.java:63)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
>     at >com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.Class_.loadClassOrStub(Class_.java:536)
>     at >com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.Class_.access$100(Class_.java:42)
>     at >com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.Class_$2.run(Class_.java:128)
>     at >com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.Class_$2.run(Class_.java:123)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at >com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.Class_.forName(Class_.java:123)
>     at utility.DAO.connect(DAO.java:31)
>     at anki_note.AnkiNote.doPost(AnkiNote.java:76)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>     at >com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
>     at >org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at >com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
>     at >org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at >com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
>     at >org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at >com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>     at >org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at >com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:254)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>     at >org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>     at >com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>     at >com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
>     at >com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:527)
>     at >com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
>     at >com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
>     at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
>     at >com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
>     at >com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
>     at >com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
>       at >com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Here is my source code to connect to my database.

```
public static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:google:mysql://caramel-clover-813:myapplication?user=root";
public static final String DB_USER = "user";
public static final String DB_PASSWORD = "xxxx";
public boolean connect()
{   
    boolean is_connect = false;

    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");

        this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        this.stmt = this.conn.createStatement();

        is_connect = true;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return is_connect;
}
```

Comment: ちなみに、上記ソースでエラーが発生しているのは下記の行です。
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");

Comment: なぜojdbcが必要なのですか？

Answer (score 1):

MySQLを利用されているのに、OracleDBのJDBCドライバを使っているようですが、MySQL接続にはmysqlのJDBCドライバ"のみ"を指定してください。

Answer (score 1):

[Using Google Cloud SQL - Java — Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#Java_Connect_to_your_database)から抜粋して回答いたします。

まず、`appengine-web.xml`に以下のように`<use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>`の記述がされているか確認してください。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  ...
  <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
</appengine-web-app>
```

次に、以下のようにして`Connection`を取得できることを確認してください。

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://your-project-id:your-instance-name/guestbook", "username", "password");
```

`DriverManager.getConnection`に渡す`url`の形式は

```
jdbc:google:mysql://<プロジェクトID>:<インスタンス名>/<データベース名>
```

であることに注意してください。`DriverManager.getConnection`に引数でユーザー名やパスワードを渡す場合は、`url`に`user`のパラメーターは不要です。